# VueJS IE11 Error SCRIPT5005 Dependency Error

Tags: vue.js, internet-explorer, babeljs, transpiler, stripe-payments

The following error occurs on IE: SCRIPT5005: String expected.

I found that the problem comes from 'vue-stripe-checkout'

In my main.js file:

```
import * as VueStripeCheckout from 'vue-stripe-checkout'
```

In my vue.config.js

```
transpileDependencies: ['vue-stripe-checkout']
```

I attached the IE Console & Debugger.
[image: IE Console]
[image: IE Debugger]

Comment: I tested with [official live demo](https://jofftiquez.github.io/vue-stripe-checkout/) in IE 11 but it can't work in IE 11. The result is [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NqhCE.png) in IE 11.Maybe this plugin is not supported by IE 11. I also didn't find browser support information about it. You could raise an issue or make a pull request in [github](https://github.com/jofftiquez/vue-stripe-checkout) about this issue.

Comment: Thanks for your time!  I will raise an issue on github.

Comment: Great! You could come back if there's any update or there's any solution for this issue.